# How to deploy loki-stack helm chart with CRIO?

Tags: kubernetes, helm, logging, grafana, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to configure [loki-stack using a helm chart](https://github.com/grafana/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/loki-stack) to my k8s cluster.

Since my k8s cluster uses CRIO and not docker (which is common nowdays) I need to change the `pipeline_stages:` config map to use [`cri: {}`](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/clients/promtail/stages/cri/) instead of `docker: {}` to parse the logs properly.

How do I change the helm chart so that `cri: {}` is used by default instead of `docker: {}` in all the `pipeline_stages:`? many thanks.

Comment: Doesn't the most recent version of that chart already use cri by default? https://github.com/grafana/helm-charts/blob/22b248efd4171a649fdef881b3f0b3a756b90809/charts/promtail/values.yaml#L239

Comment: for some reason when i deploy the loki-stack helm chart, it deploys it with docker... I did actually try in my requirements.yaml to require the latest version by doing `version: "^3.5.0"` for promtail and it keeps deploying docker :(

Comment: @Briansbum, per your comment, i've attempted to deploy loki-stack in a katacoda k8s cluster independently of my own cluster and I can confirm that it used `docker: {}` instead of `cri: {}` as well. I think that the helm chart has a snippet using cri but is not actually using it and something needs to be done to make it use `cri: {}` instead of `docker: {}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to solve this by changing the `values.yaml` in the `loki-stack` helm chart to the following:

```
promtail:
  enabled: true
  pipelineStages:
  - cri: {}
```

Enjoy.